# Plotting vector to a line

Tags: javascript, python, math, vector, linear-algebra

I'm working on a simulation in which I have an aircraft and I need to be able to fly to a starting point of a line. When arriving at that point, it needs to be aligned with the angle of the line. The starting point can be either point on the line. It is similar to simulating an aircraft landing on a runway but I do not need to factor in altitude.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPBl1.jpg)

I have the following information:

- aircraft vector

  - latitude/longitude
  - heading
  - speed
- destination line (two points)

  - point 1 latitude/longitude
  - point 2 latitude/longitude

Aircraft position is updated every 0.5 second and is limited to 3 degrees per second turn rate.

I am currently using Jean Brouwers python interpretation of geodesy tools (https://github.com/mrJean1/PyGeodesy) for a lot of my trigonometric and vector-based methods.

I'm looking for a way to plot my aircraft to the destination line with the proper heading.

Any help with the rationale or math would be greatly appreciated. It's been a long time since I have done any complex trig.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem in a field of [**Optimal control**](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Optimal_synthesis_control), if you really want to deal with plane speed and position, not just to build a smooth graph connecting two or three dots.

This is a theory for finding control functions that can bring mathematical systems from one state to another.

Your goal is to represent everything as a system of variables: state variables `x(t)` (position in rectangular or polar coordinates, direction, speed) and control variables `u(t)` (throttle position, steering position). Then you describe dependencies between them as a system of differential equations `x'(t) = f(x(t), u(t))`.

And for that mathematical system, applying constraints s on your control variables and providing sets of target values of state variables, you synthesize a control functions for control variables. Synthesizing relies heavily on [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle).

Check out simple examples of applying the theory, if you can.

Of course, it is a general approach which is used in real aviation and spaceships... Maybe you don't really need this and something simpler's gonna fit :)

Comment: The fidelity of your answer is greater than what I needed but it looks like it would work for more complex simulations. Since I didn't require such fidelity, I was able to use a handful of cases to do what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @Jake very glad to help!